# When should we use @Transactional annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I wanted to know when we should use `@Transactional` in Spring Boot Services.

Since JpaRepository's `save()` method is annotated with `@Tranasactional` is it required for me to add that annotation in my service method?

I've seen a couple of articles saying that if there is only a repository being used inside your service method (like in the below scenario) then it's not required to put `@Transactional` on the service method as `save()` is already annotated with `@Transactional`. Is it true?

```java
class EmployeeService {
    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepository repo;
        
    @Transactional //(Is it required here?)
    public void saveEmployee(Employee employee) {
        repo.save(employee)
    }
}
```

Should it be used in this below case on method `getStudentsWithNameStartsWithAndGradeLessThan()` since we are using more than one Repository?

```java
@Getter 
@Setter 
@Entity 
@Table(name = "student") 
public class Student { 
      @Id 
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
      @Column(name = "id", nullable = false) 
      private Long id; 
     
      @Column(name = "name") 
      private String name; 
     
      @Column(name = "average_grade") 
      private Short averageGrade; 
}
```

```java
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> { 
      Set<Student> findByAverageGradeLessThan(Short averageGrade); 
      Set<Student> findByNameStartsWithIgnoreCase(String name); 
}
```

```java
@Service 
public class StudentService { 
     
      private final StudentRepository studentRepository; 
     
      public StudentService(StudentRepository studentRepository) { 
        this.studentRepository = studentRepository; 
      } 
     
       @Transactional //(Is it required here?)
      public Set<Student> getStudentsWithNameStartsWithAndGradeLessThan(String prefix, Short averageGrade) {
     
       Set<Student> students = studentRepository.findByNameStartsWithIgnoreCase(prefix); 
       students.retainAll(studentRepository.findByAverageGradeLessThan(averageGrade)); 
        return students; 
    
    } 
}
```

Comment: You can youse it anyware. I don't understand the question. You've seen a couple of articles, did you share any of them? Do you have any problem with the code? Use it if you need it, but I guess you don't know what is this annotation means.

Comment: @RomanC I do know what it does, but I'm really not sure if I'm using it in the right place.

Comment: If you don't know it then why did you use it?

Comment: Yes you need it on your service method as that is your transactional boundary. The business usecase you execute. If you are updating multiple things you want that to happen in 1 transaction, not in 3 (or whatever number of save method calls you do) single transactions. For reading in theory you could omit it, but you will run into nice issues if you depend on lazy loading, next to that there is always a tx on the database side of things so it is alway sbetter to be in control of that.

Answer (score 4):

If you want spring transaction management to act for you for opening transaction, committing and also take care of rollback on your behave. Specially if you are working with multiple tables, You should use this, This acts as AOP and make sure transaction is either committed or rollback.

It's not mandatory to you this annotation, rather a good practice to let spring manage your complete cross tables transactions for consistency.

If you don't use this annotation, Spring Data JPA normally delegates transaction management to the underlying persistence provider (e.g., Hibernate, Eclipse etc) or relies on the default transaction configuration of your Spring application context.

Consider below sample example, If I get exception while saving into 2nd table, My transaction should be rollback for 1st table as well. This can be done with @Transactional which will take care of boiler plate code.

```
@Transactional
public void processOrder(Order order) {
    // Save order details
    orderRepository.save(order);

    // Update product quantity
    Product product = productRepository.findById(order.getProductId()).orElse(null);
    if (product != null) {
        int newQuantity = product.getQuantity() - order.getQuantity();
        if (newQuantity >= 0) {
            product.setQuantity(newQuantity);
            productRepository.save(product);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Insufficient quantity in stock");
        }
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Product not found");
    }
}
```

[More information here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/data-access/transaction/declarative/annotations.html)

Answer (score 0):

To complete the comments that you got on the question, I would say:

Yes it is true that `save()` method already has `@Transactional` annotation, you could see it on your own if you open implementation of it.

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {
    Assert.notNull(entity, "Entity must not be null");
    if (this.entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        this.em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return this.em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

If your method invoke just this method and nothing else it do not make sense to add it.

Let`s say your method have next one body:

```
    @Transactional
    public void saveEmployee(Employee employee) {
    
    repo.save(employee)
    userTrackerRepo.update() // or any other repo invocation or validation that if fails then save method should do rollback.
   }
```

Then it make senses to have `@Transactional` annotation

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, if an interface involves modifying multiple database tables, transactions should be used to avoid data inconsistencies. In your first piece of code, it seems to be a save operation, but if multiple tables are involved, you can add the @Transactional annotation. In your second piece of code, which seems to be a database query operation, you should also add transactions if multiple database tables are involved. In general, the need for additional transactions is determined by the specific business situation..